# MYSQL query - simple way to return all values from one column based on a DISTINCT value in another column in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm scratching my head a little on this one and I'm sure it's pretty basic but it's been a little.

If I have a two column table that basically has a structure like:

table: *customer_per_store*

```
pid, store_id
```

where pid is a unique key and store_id can have multiple repeated value:

E.g.

```
1, 500
2, 500
3, 500
4, 505
5, 505
7, 0
8, 500
9, 0
```

What is the correct query for a result that grabs ALL pids to a DISTINCT store_id but we ignore store_ids with a value of 0?

Is this easily possible? I feel like this is ridiculously easy?

I guess I could do it in two statements where first I get all DISTINCT store_ids, save the results to an array and and then a loop through that array performing a query for each store_id and saving the results.

Is there an easier way to do this through in a single mysql query though?

Ideally in a single query I could get a result such as:

```
[500] => Array(
   [0] => 1,
   [1] => 2,
   [2] => 3
   ...
), 
[505] => Array(
   [0] => 4,
   [1] => 5
)
```

etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using php because of the debug output.

I think you just want to stack your results in an associative array where the key is the store_id. This example uses `mysqli_query` but you can adapt it to pdo.

```
$results_by_store_id = array();
$rs = mysqli_query("select * from customer_per_store where store_id <> 0");
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $results_by_store_id[$r['store_id']][] = $r['pid'];
}

print_r($results_by_store_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `group_concat()`:

```
select store_id, group_concat(pid)
from table t
where store_id <> 0
group by store_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job, if you use a `GROUP BY` variant, you'll still have to post process the data into an array.

The query you want is pretty simple:

```
  SELECT store_id, pid
    FROM table t
   WHERE store_id != 0
```

Then use your language of choice to run through the resultant assoc array and build the array you want out of it.. here's some php code:

```
$processed = [];
foreach($fetched as $row){
  $processed[$row['store_id']][] = $row['pid']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want something like: `SELECT pid, store_id FROM <your_database> WHERE store_id > 0 GROUP BY store_id`?

This groups all pids that have a distinct store_id under that store_id.

This might not be the exact query you want, but I definitly think you can achieve this with `GROUP BY`.